# Is it possible to get Place Image through Google autocomplete API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

Can it be a possibility to Get Place(Country,City) Image automatically when i select address by **Google autocomplete API**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Google Places API Web Service - Place Photos](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) is what you need.

The Place Photo service is a read-only API that allows you to add high quality photographic content to your application.

All requests to the Place Photo service must include a `photoreference`, returned in the response to a [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) or [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) request. The response to these requests will contain a `photos[]` field if the place has related photographic content. Each `photo` element in this array will contain `photo_reference`, which is what you need.

Here is an example of `photos[]`array:

```
...
"photos" : [
   {
      "html_attributions" : [],
      "height" : 853,
      "width" : 1280,
      "photo_reference" : "CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0"
   }
...
```

And here is an actual example of HTTP URL Place Photo request (You have to put the aforementioned `photo_reference`in the request):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

In case of a successful request, the response will be an image.